# How to add data file to Windows Universal app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am working on a Universal app, initially targeting Windows Phone 8.1.

I have an XML file that I would like to package/ship along with the app, which the app will read when it's being run and will also update it.

I've found examples of how to read and save to a local folder but nothing about how to ship data along with the app and read it.

Should the XML file be added as a resource?  Or should it be stored in the local folder? If so, how do I add the file to that folder ahead of time?  In a previous app I added XML files as resources, however that app was for Windows Phone 8 and the Universal apps seem to have changed how a lot of things are done so I am not sure what the best option is here.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only way to ship data with the app is to include it in appx package by adding it to your project and marking it as content. This will place it in the app's read-only install directory.

To update the file you'll need to copy it to the application data folders. I'd probably write an access function to get the file which loads it from the local folder if it exists there. If not, then copy it over.

--Rob